# in-app billing for subscriptions

Tags: in-app-billing, subscriptions

I am planning to sell an android application on Google play with the subscription model as follows

- 1.99/month (includes a 30 day free trial. The first billing date is set to today+30)
  -19.99/year (includes a 60 day free trial. the first billing date is set to today+60)

I have implemented the logic for this pricing and the application is working fine.

Now, I would like to offer an additional 30 days of free service to those customers that report an issue with using the application. In order to do this, I like to just update the next billing date. The question does google play allow such an update using google play server-side api? If yes, I may just develop a console app for and admin to add the 30 days to next billing date for the specific customer reporting the issue.

Can someone help me, if this approach works and point me with a link to server-side API and a sample showing how to consume? Alternatively, can someone suggest an alternative approach to meet this requirement

Srinivas

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seems so. According to [Google Play Android Developer API v1](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/) you have only 2 methods which you can use to communicate with the Playstore Server:

**cancel** - Cancels a user's subscription purchase. The subscription remains valid until its expiration time.
**get** - Checks whether a user's subscription purchase is valid and returns its expiry time.

As a whole, Google doesn't let you tamper with users' subscriptions. I don't really see an approach to your problem without using your own server where you can manage the subscriptions on your own and just ask the Google server for the real expiry date.